# using data from html forms in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<form action='main.php' method='POST'>
<select name="Category" class='listbox'>
<?php $cat = mysql_query("select cName from category");
while($drop = mysql_fetch_array($cat))
{
    echo '<option value="' . $drop['Category'] . '">' . $drop['cName'] . '</option>';
}
?>
<input type='text' name='search' class='namebox'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' class='submitbox'></select>
</select>
```

i am trying to use this form to create a search engine from my database but just cant get the value from the drop down menu.

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if($submit)
{
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $catval = $_POST['Category'];
    echo $catval ;
    $searchval = mysql_query("select * from item where iname like '%$search%'and cId in (select cId from category where cName = '$catval')");
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($searchval))
    {
        echo "Item Name: " . $info['iName'];
    }
}
```

so when i try to search using this method i get no results.

Comment: You should not query all fields (not use the * operator) and limit the result number. Don't process raw user input but unescape it or, even better, use prepared statements (with PDO) to make SQL injections impossible. SQL injections are a serious security problem.

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).**

Comment: Please note that I meant "escape", not "unescape" it. Unfortunately, my comment can no longer be edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed the selects closing tag wrong :) and I assume you remembered to close your form aswell?

```
<form action='main.php' method='POST'>
<select name="Category" class='listbox'>
<?php $cat = mysql_query("select cName, Category from category");
while($drop = mysql_fetch_array($cat))
{
    echo '<option value="' . $drop['Category'] . '">' . $drop['cName'] .'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type='text' name='search' class='namebox'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' class='submitbox'> 
</form>
```

Comment: still when i echo $catval i get nothing

Comment: You have closed your form right? I mean you have the </form> at the end of your inputs?

Comment: See my updated answer, you forgot to fetch the Category from your first query, you only fetched cName

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='main.php' method='POST'>
<select name="Category" class='listbox'>
<?php $cat = mysql_query("select cName from category");
while($drop = mysql_fetch_array($cat))
{
    echo '<option value="' . $drop['Category'] . '">' . $drop['cName'] .         
'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type='text' name='search' class='namebox'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' class='submitbox'>
</form>
```

That should do the trick. Your `</select>` was in the wrong place.

In the meantime, you might [want to look into PDO and bound values](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of using `mysql()` as it's  depreciated (I.E. don't use it anymore) and insecure.